# Delete all backup tables automatically using MySQL database version 8.0.12

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between, drop

On MySQL database version 8.0.12 I have this data table set as table master.

```
t_table_southwest
```

For each month on days from 1th to 15th, I have programmed the daily backup of the master table.

These are the backup tables

```
t_table_southwest_20220401
t_table_southwest_20220402
t_table_southwest_20220403
t_table_southwest_20220404
t_table_southwest_20220405
t_table_southwest_20220406
t_table_southwest_20220407
t_table_southwest_20220408
t_table_southwest_20220409
t_table_southwest_20220410
t_table_southwest_20220411
t_table_southwest_20220412
t_table_southwest_20220413
t_table_southwest_20220414
t_table_southwest_20220415
```

When the current date is greater than the date of day 15 (last day of the table backup) I need to automatically delete all backup tables and keep only the master table.

I can generate a range of contiguous dates in MySQL with a query like this **[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5T3qr61DP2qtDDaWUnpBgA/1)**

Any suggestion for delete all backup tables automatically?

**Solution**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5T3qr61DP2qtDDaWUnpBgA/2

Comment: You may be able to use the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html) to cover tasks such as that. (kind of like a CRON, in a way)

Comment: @PaulT. thanks for reply, i have posted my solution on the question. This is OK as it is a two step process, one to generate the Drop statement and the other to copy and run this statement into the command line and run it.